# Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' - on a VM scale Set Azure Windows Data center 2019

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, command-line-interface

We have an Azure Powershell task within Azure DevOps that is trying to run and install:

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 1.6.2 -Force
Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -Force
```

For the DevOps Agent pool I have an `Azure Scaleset` of two VMs on OS `Windows 2019 Data Center`
When running the DevOps Pipeline we get the following error:

```
##[error]Initializing Az module failed: For troubleshooting, refer: https://aka.ms/azurepowershelltroubleshooting
##[error]Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: ''. If the module was recently installed, retry after restarting the Azure Pipelines task agent
```

The DevOps task is configured to Azure Powershell task v.4 + latest version.
When running with on the defaul Azure DevOps agent with windows-2019 the script works.
Any ideas what am I missing here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try to run the `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to list all modules.az.accounts/azurern  hasn't been installed on your vmss pool. But windows2019 agent has installed these module , so it could work fine.

Comment: than I get the error: The term 'pwsh.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: This issue is that you enable the powershell core option, but the powershell core hasn't been installed on the agent